# How to concatenate this array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do i concatenate these two arrays to get the expected output?

```js
let bidder= [
  [1,2,3,4],
  [5,6,7,8]
]

let arr1 = [9,10,11,12]
```

expected result

```js
[
(4) [...],
(4) [...],
(4) [...],
]
```

Comment: Try `bidder.push(arr1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const bidder= [
  [1,2,3,4],
  [5,6,7,8]
]

const arr1 = [9,10,11,12];
const result = [...bidder, arr1];
console.log(result);
```

You can use `spread` operator to spread whatever is in bidder array and add your other array as the last one in a new array.